# Installing Vegas Pro 9 - Windows 7 - Installation Package Error

Tags: windows-7, sony-vegas

I'm trying to install Vegas Pro 9 on my laptop here, it's running windows 7 - 64 bit. When I run the installer, It starts then when I click to proceed with the installation I get an error :

"The Installation package could not be opened. Verify that the package exists and that you can access it", or contact the application vendor to verify that is a valid Windows installer package."

I have tried running it as admin, changed the compatibility for older versions of windows. This one has stumped me! Can you please please help me?

*Note: I installed the same file on my desktop and it work fine but my desktop doesn't have as much ram as my laptop, plus I want to bring this to school. My desktop has the same specs as my desktop except for the ram. The program works perfectly on my desktop but i can't even install it on my laptop?*

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the installer is corrupted. Try downloading it again.